# Azure Devops: Run a task based on input json config condition

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps release pipeline which reads an input JSON in Powershell having the format

```
{
  "activities": [
     "activityA",
     "activityB",
     "activityC"
  ]
}
```

Now, depending on which activity has been specified, I need to run that corresponding task in the release pipeline and not all the activities. So, in the above, if `activityB` is not specified, then the task to install it should not run.

I know we can use custom conditional expressions to run a task, but not sure how to read a JSON array in PowerShell and use that in the custom conditional expression.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the JSON with `ConvertFrom-Json` method, then check what he contain and set variables for use in the conditional expression.

For example:

```
$json = '{
  "activities": [
     "activityA",
     "activityB",
     "activityC"
  ]
}' | ConvertFrom-Json

if($json.activities.Contains("activityA"))
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=activityA]true"

}
if($json.activities.Contains("activityB"))
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=activityB]true"
}
if($json.activities.Contains("activityC"))
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=activityC]true"
}
```

Now in the conditional expression use the variables `activityA` `activityB` `activityC`.